# Puedo usar tcpdump para escuchar la salida de un servicio soap?

Tags: linux, http, tcp

Tengo un servidor en Linux  y en ese mismo servidor tengo montado un weblogic y un war que usa axis para los servicios soap.

Lo que quiero obtener es el mensaje soap que envío desde mi servidor y va con destino a otro. Con el fin de ver porque mi mensaje soap no funciona cuando va de salida pero si cuando se trabaja en modo local sin salirse del mismo servidor.

Intente usar este comando para escuchar y solo me imprime el contenido que genera el war del lado del navegador

```
tcpdump -i eth0 'port 80'
```

Intente todos estos pero me da el mismo resultado:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 src 192.168.3.1 -w traficored.log
```

Use el src y dst pero ninguno captura el mensaje soap que va de salida.

Si solo uso el tcpdump dts/src ipdelservidor me marca error : tcpdump: USB link-layer type filtering not implemented.

Se me acabaron las opciones y solo quiero leer el mensaje soap que va de salida hacia otro servidor. Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿No has tratado de usar el fiddler o postman?  Aunque es del cliente al servidor al menos te da idea de que responde

Comment: Al weblogic dale el nivel de log mas bajo no me acuerdo  si  es TRACE o DEBUG. Eso hace que bote toda la actividad al log,.

Comment: No, lo que quiero hacer es diferente, cuando se ejecuta mi programa y hacer el envío desde ahí quiero ver porque el otro servidor me rechaza el servicio soap, localmente hice una prueba y el servicio se enviaba bien. Luego envié un mensaje soap dese local haciendo puente con el servidor de Linux y este se iba a servidor externo y funcionaba. Estoy comenzando a creer que es el weblogic que tiene problemas pero para eso quiero ver cómo se envía el mensaje. Pude captura dese el local al servidor el mensaje soap con los comando que mencioné pero no puedo hacer lo mismo con lo que va de salida

Comment: Cuando dices rechaza el servicio soap es que te retorna un mensaje de error. ¿cuál el error que retorna? Has probado  haciendo un ping o tracert desde el weblogic al servidor externo. Me parece que el web logiv no sale hacia la red externa. Tienes proxys o firewalñs

Comment: Igual debes mirar los logs del Weblogic  te va ayudar mas que hacerle  un  dump. Es una conexión segura?

Comment: El mensaje de error es un mensaje muy general que colocaron las otras personas, ni siquiera yo sé cuál es el error. el problema se presenta cuando envío archivos por soap, porque cuando envío un mensaje soap sin archivos el servidor  externo me devuce un success , pero cuando envío archivos regresa systen err. Si monto un weblogic en mi laptop y desde ahí levando el sistema y hago un puente de mi laptop a mi servidor para alcanzar la IP del servidor y de ahí mandarlo al otro servidor funciona bien. Pero desde el weblogic del servidor no funciona.

Comment: Ya intenté ver el log del weblogic y el out y nada parece extraño. Ppr eso quería ver el mensaje soap que se envía hacia el otro server y ver si de salida va bien el soap con los archivos codificado. No sé si el weblogic del servidor le colocaron algo para que no vaya bien la petición

Comment: De repente no  tiene  salida  hacia afuera. No me dijiste si por algun proxy o fire. Desde el weblogic haz `ping` hacia el servidor externo para  que descartes red.

Comment: Ah lo siento, de eso sí no tengo idea ya que solo es un servidor para desarrollar. Bueno eso de descartar si es la conexión no puede ser, porque si envío un mensaje soap desde mi servidor al otro, el mensaje soap lo recibe sin problemas.

Comment: haz `tcpdump --interface any` para que captures todo y  vayas luego filtrando a lo que ves.  No dices que  sale los mensaje?

Comment: Lo haré. Es como dije arriba, cuando envío un mensaje soap al servidor de destino lo recibe sin problemas. Pero cuando el mensaje soap lleva archivos ya no se registra y me manda el error de systen err. Si hago la misma operación desde mi máquina local funciona todo hasta con archivos. Aquí el tema pareces ser el weblogic del servidor donde subo mi war. Por eso queria ver qué mensaje envía el weblgoci del servidor de desarrollo al otro servidor